# Sending variable through peer.js

Tags: javascript, server, peer

I'am creating a webapp with peer.js. It's an app where you can see eachother through the webcam, by just submitting the ID from the other person through the server from peer.js.

It's working quite good, but I want to be able to send a variable to the other person. The reason that I want this is because I want to create a button which whenever it's pushed, the other person hears a sound.

Like:

```
$('.button').click(function()
{
   var clicked = true;
   //send var clicked to the other person so I can use an if statement there
}
```

I have 2 problems. I don't know how to send this variable to the other person through the peer server and it's with done by jquery so I'am not sure if I can use the variable as a global variable for the javascript code.

```
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.controls').hide();
      $('.bovenlijst').hide();
      $('.fotomaken').hide();
    });
    // Compatibility shim
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    // PeerJS object
    var peer = new Peer({ key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9', debug: 3, config: {'iceServers': [
      { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' } // Pass in optional STUN and TURN server for maximum network compatibility
    ]}});


    peer.on('open', function(){
      $('#my-id').text(peer.id);
      console.log(peer.id);
    });

    // Receiving a call
    peer.on('call', function(call){
      // Answer the call automatically (instead of prompting user) for demo purposes
      call.answer(window.localStream);
      step3(call);
    });
    peer.on('error', function(err){
      alert(err.message);
      // Return to step 2 if error occurs
      step2();
    });

    // Click handlers setup
    $(function(){
      $('#make-call').click(function(){
        // Initiate a call!
        var call = peer.call($('#callto-id').val(), window.localStream);
        $('#step2').hide();
        $('.controls').show();
        $('.bovenlijst').show();
        $('.fotomaken').show();
        step3(call);

      });

      $('#end-call').click(function(){
        window.existingCall.close();
        step2();
      });

      // Retry if getUserMedia fails
      $('#step1-retry').click(function(){
        $('#step1-error').hide();
        step1();
      });

      // Get things started
      step1();
    });

    function step1 () {
      // Get audio/video stream
      navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream){
        // Set your video displays
        $('#my-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));

        window.localStream = stream;
        step2();
      }, function(){ $('#step1-error').show(); });
    }

    function step2 () {
      $('#step1, #step3').hide();
      $('#step2').show();
    }

    function step3 (call) {
      // Hang up on an existing call if present
      if (window.existingCall) {
        window.existingCall.close();
      }

      // Wait for stream on the call, then set peer video display
      call.on('stream', function(stream){
        $('#their-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
      });

      // UI stuff
      window.existingCall = call;
      $('#their-id').text(call.peer);
      call.on('close', step2);
      $('#step1, #step2').hide();
      $('#step3').show();
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to open additionally to the media connection a data connection to the other peer. That way you can pass data like variables between the clients.
This functionality is included in PeerJS.

From the documentation extended with the use of a variable:

Connect:

```
var myVariable = 'this is a test';
var conn = peer.connect('another-peers-id');
conn.on('open', function(){
  conn.send(myVariable);
});
```

Receive

```
peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
  conn.on('data', function(data){
    // Will print 'this is a test'
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

See also at http://peerjs.com/

Comment: but how about adding parameters while connecting (to peerserver), so we can for example define "a peer with an INTEREST-TAG" so we can later randomly connect peers with same INTEREST-TAGs?